# IBM Worklight : Flow of sample Push Notification project seems wrong on windows phone

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone, ibm-mobilefirst

I am running the sample push notification hybrid project provided by IBM in windows phone environment. When the app starts, the screen with the four buttons loads up first. Is this the normal flow for the app or should the login page load first followed by the page with the four buttons ? I didn't face this issue while working on android environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample application for push notification does not come by default with the Windows environment. It comes with the Android environment.

To force the application to start with a login screen also on Windows you'll want to protect the application with a security test.

Open application-descriptor.xml, find the Windows environment element and add the following attribute: `securityTest="your-custom-securitytest-name"` (like the Android environment).